Git: CredentialHelperSelector appears whenever I try push
I have a repository that is 2 years old. All files were not pushed up for reason I do not remember. I copied it to another external drive since I had to format the machine and then moved to other things. Recently I got a new laptop and copied the repository into this machine.
The first problem I had was related to "ownership". I saw that when I used whoami /user, I am not a different user than what was on the machine when this repository was created and its initial commits were pushed to GitHub. I eventually solved this using the takeown /f repo_dir /r /d y command. Otherwise, even git status would not function with this repository.
Now I am able to commit code to this repository and add it to SourceTree. But I am unable to do git push! The remote is present on GitHub. I am using free version of GitHub which is sufficient. Everytime I try to do push using terminal or SourceTree GUI, I get this:

I do not remember how I set things up 2 years old. But I am able to log into GitHub where this repository exists. The question is, what do I need to do to get the credentials to be able to push to this remote today? I believe it has something to do with something called SSH or HTTPS but don't remember the details anymore. I have chosen many options from this pop-up but it comes back again. I believe that I have to change something in some configuration file of Git somewhere but am not sure if that really is the fix for this! Maybe I need to delete everything in Windows Credential Manager so Git will try to get them from scratch, I am not sure.
If someone could kindly give me some guidance, it shall be highly appreciated.

OK so I did realize that Git has introduced some sort of credential manager for Git to make the Git repositories more secure. This Git credential manager now comes with Git and can be installed when Git is being installed on the computer. I confirmed that I have it since git-credential-manager was being accepted on my machine. It printed this:
$ git-credential-manager
Required command was not provided.

git-credential-manager

Usage:
  git-credential-manager [options] [command]

Options:
  --version       Show version information
  -?, -h, --help  Show help and usage information

Commands:
  get          [Git] Return a stored credential
  store        [Git] Store a credential
  erase        [Git] Erase a stored credential
  configure    Configure Git Credential Manager as the Git credential helper
  unconfigure  Unconfigure Git Credential Manager as the Git credential helper
  diagnose     Run diagnostics and gather logs to diagnose problems with Git Credential Manager
  azure-repos  Commands for interacting with the Azure Repos host provider

I then executed these two commands:
gyu@DESKTOP-TOOMUCHTROUBLE /cygdrive/e/My_Designs/FPGA/jpeg_encoder
$ git-credential-manager configure
Configuring component 'Git Credential Manager'...
Configuring component 'Azure Repos provider'...

gyu@DESKTOP-TOOMUCHTROUBLE /cygdrive/e/My_Designs/FPGA/jpeg_encoder
$ git-credential-manager diagnose
Running diagnostics...

 [ OK ] Environment
 [ OK ] File system
 [ OK ] Networking
 [ OK ] Git
 [ OK ] Credential storage
 [ OK ] Microsoft authentication (AAD/MSA)
 [ OK ] GitHub API

Diagnostic summary: 7 passed, 0 skipped, 0 failed.
Log files:
  E:\My_Designs\FPGA\jpeg_encoder\gcm-diagnose.log

Caution: Log files may include sensitive information - redact before sharing.

I did this inside terminal opened from within SourceTree and also the Cygwin. I use Cygwin in place of WSL, PowerShell and CMD. Now, I am able to push code from source tree and also by typing git push in terminal. Problem solved.
